# Conversão de arquivo RPT para PDF c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Bom dia

Tenho o seguinte arquivo em `.rtp` e, preciso converter/transformar os dados desse relatório para `pdf`.

> SaldoEstoqueEmpresa.rpt

Preciso que seja feito isso através de um evento click.

Answer (score 1):

Se o relatório que você quer em pdf será gerado no rpt, então você precisa criar o relatório antes de transformar em pdf, algo como isto:

```
public void GerarRelatorio(){
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;
        string HIJRA_TODAY = "01/10/1435";
        ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[3];
        param[0] = new ReportParameter("CUSTOMER_NUM", CUSTOMER_NUMTBX.Text);
        param[1] = new ReportParameter("REF_CD", REF_CDTB.Text);
        param[2] = new ReportParameter("HIJRA_TODAY", HIJRA_TODAY);

        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", 
            null, 
            out mimeType, 
            out encoding, 
            out extension, 
            out streamIds, 
            out warnings);

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", 
            "attachment; filename= filename" + "." + extension);
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // create the file  
        Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download  
        Response.End();
}
```

Aqui tem um post com uma dúvida semelhante a sua: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background

Comment: Na verdade quero gerar este relatório .rpt para .pdf